# Mongoose query model where field type is an array

Tags: node.js, database, express, mongoose

I had to change the schema type of a field (location) in my Course model from array to string, I however need to change all previous data I have from type array to string and then do some data manipulation to get what I need. New data are being stored as String. How do I query all courses having **location field type as array and where zip code exists** so that I can do proper data manipulation?

```
const coursesWithArrayLocation = await Course.find({zipcode: { $exists: true }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator to match specific type of field,

- match type by 2 ways first is `Number` and second is `Alias`, where array type Number is **4** and Alias is **"array"**

```
const coursesWithArrayLocation = await Course.find({
  location: { $type: "array" },
  zipcode: { $exists: true }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/phgB5mYQHoQ)